# Restrict multiple page access by a user from the same IP

Tags: php, mysql, ip

I am coding a script, that will restrict multiple access for a particular user from a given IP address. In other words, a given user will only be able to access/view the page one time from the same IP address.

But how do I compare the incoming IP's to detect this kind of access?

I want to Track IPs for 60 days max.

Comment: save the IPs in a DB , do a lookup when the user comes , and depending upon the match redirect him/her to suitable page

Comment: Can this be done without Database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to store IPs in a database or flat file somewhere for comparison.

Let's imagine you have a MySQL table `visits` such as this:

```
`ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
`last_visit` datetime NOT NULL,
`visits` int(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ip`)
```

Using PHP we can get the user's IP, create or update a table record in the database, and then do some comparison.

```
<?php

// Get the user's IP
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

// Create a database record, or update if they're been here before
$dblink = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'username', 'password' );
mysql_select_db( 'database', $dblink );
$rs = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO visits (ip, date_created, last_visit, visits) VALUES( '$ip', NOW(), NOW(), 1 ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `last_visit` = NOW(), visits=visits+1 ", $dblink );

// Compare database record for last visit and first visit
$rs = mysql_query( "SELECT visits, DATEDIFF( last_visit, date_created ) as sincelast FROM visits WHERE `ip` = '$ip' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $rs );

// If this is their first visit, do one thing, otherwise, do another.
if ( $row['sincelast'] > 59 || $row['visits'] < 2 ) {
    // They visited 60+ days ago, or this is their first visit
} else {
    // This is not their first visit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, different computers/users can and do share an IP address. You may prevent a lot of people from visiting your site simply because somebody in their workplace also visited. That being said, here's my answer.

You tagged `MySQL`, so create a table called "ips" - or something similar.

- ID
- IP
- lastAccess

Whenever somebody visits your site, check to see if their IP address is found within this table, and if the lastAccess date is within 60 days of today. If it is, reject or redirect the request. If their IP is not in the table, or the date is greater than 60 days from today, insert/update the table to contain their IP, and the current time, then permit them to view the requested page.

This doesn't need to be done in a database, you could perform similar logic in a flat-file system. However you'd have a lot of file-opening, reading, writing, and this might be a bit frustrating as you may attempt to write to the file as you're currently attempting to read from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on doing this & doing without database then you may want to store the visit data inside a file and access it to check the first visit time for the ip. Of course this is pretty much the same as using a database in theory.

An example function to do what i suggested above: 
(Note that this is very rough and unreliable to use as it is)

```
function allowedIP() {
    $vFile = 'vfile'; // file to store visitor data
    $revisit = 3600*24*60; // not allowed time in seconds
    $now = time(); // visit time
    $vIP = ip2long( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ); // get the ip and convert to long
    $vData = ( file_exists( $vFile ) ) ? 
        unserialize( file_get_contents( $vFile ) ) : array(); // get the visit data
    if( ! isset( $vData[$vIP] ) || $now - $vData[$vIP] > $revisit ) {
        // first visit or 60 days passed since the first visit
        $vData[$vIP] = $now; // store the visit time
        file_put_contents( $vFile, serialize( $vData ) ); // save to file
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage of this function would be like:

```
if( ! allowedIP() ) { /* ip is not allowed, notify the visitor and don't proceed */  }
```

Answer (score 0):

well you need a list of IPs somewhere to lookup against , so you can use a table or write it to a file and then read accordingly

Comment: Skeletal answer, but hardly worth a downvote.

Comment: I too am shocked on the downvote. What wrong did I do ?

Answer (score 0):

User `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the user's IP, but it's not the best plan, because multiple users using the same proxy will appear to your server as one IP = one user. Then store it in a database.

A better idea is to set a cookie on the user's browser that tells you they've already visited. They could cheat, though. But they can also cheat the IP's by using a different proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a BIG but - IPs are not unique to machines, or people for that matter. So what is the logic?