# How to deny multiple connections (or multiple instances of) a particular webpage to the same IP address client?

Tags: php

Consider a webpage  say, http://www.somedomain.tld/page1.php
I don't want someone open page1.php's more than one instances. If the user opens, the same page in multiple browsers he gets disconnected with a warning message.

Any suggestions how to proceed with this? Possible cookie check, simple .htaccess implementation,IP check?

Please let me know if you need further clarifications regarding the scenario.

LINKED: [Restrict multiple page access by a user from the same IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393398/restrict-multiple-page-access-by-a-user-from-the-same-ip?lq=1)

EDIT: accepted "[deceze's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13645313/1866195)" direction.

@Mods : You may please close this question.

Comment: It is virtually impossible to do this without side effects which may or may not be pretty bad. Please define *why* you want to break the web so badly?

Comment: Cookies are out of question -- multiple browsers. IP -- IPs could be shared.

Comment: What about people at home on a wireless network? (sharing one external IP) Only one person could use the site at a time?

Comment: @deceze - 'break the web'? I am shortsighted on the pun. If you are talking about possible applications for this, my goal is preventing a current logged in user from a particular pool to generate another request, until his first request is completed by the server. Other 'whys'..a simultaneous shopping cart /payment processing or as generic as may be try deter a DDOS attack

Comment: @Dale - my idea is to block a 'single' person from generating two requests. I guess, with shared IPs, a block based on IPs will defeat the purpose, right?

Comment: It's not a pun, it *is* breaking the default idempotent behavior of the web. A single request is only a single request. After the request-response cycle is over, your server has no idea whether the user is still there, still has the browser open, is still interacting with the website or not. What if the user closes the browser window and opens the site in another browser? It's virtually impossible for your server to detect this, but you want to break this typical expected behavior on purpose.

Comment: I'm just throwing out situations you may not have thought of, and I must say when I'm shopping online I don't open two tabs in my browser to the same site, can't speak for everyone else.

Comment: @deceze - i get your point, that's the general modus operandi of a site visitor. but in my case i may been trying to achieve the 'impossible' under my own constrained site framework. in an absence of the active user login system .

Comment: @Dale i was trying to think of exceptions on my web app

Comment: you have **transactions** on server side to protect against `a simultaneous shopping cart /payment processing or as generic as may be try deter a DDOS attack` or even reloads(F5). if all submits have an unique-id you can be sure that you process them only one time, regardless how many times they were submited

Comment: @LuisSiquot can you give me a link were i can read more into this? Sorry for being a noob .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the two tools you have here are IPs and cookies.

IPs are not unique to a user. Forget about them. IPs are a delivery mechanism for routing data, they are way too coarse to identify users.

Cookies are not shared across browsers, so you cannot identify a user using cookies cross-browser.

Additionally, the web is stateless. There isn't one persistent connection between the browser and the server while the web site is open. Once the page is loaded, it stays open in the browser, but there's no communication between it and the server going on.

Given these circumstances, it's virtually impossible to do what you ask for using IPs or cookies. At least without some side effects, which may range from a user logging himself out of his own account or people who share the same IP dead-locking each other.

What you should do is to write your app in a way that's embracing the stateless nature of HTTP requests. You can identify a user by giving him a unique cookie. Conversely, a user without cookie is a new user (including different browsers); use this information to your advantage. If you need a certain process to be finished before something else can be done, you need to keep this state server-side and tie it to a specific user. I.e. *"the user with cookie XYZ needs to do action C next"*, then when the user makes an HTTP request to your server, have the server evaluate the request and decide whether it fits in with whatever the user is *supposed* to do; respond appropriately by redirecting or denying the request.

Comment: Perfect! I think i got my answer in this phrase, "a user without cookie is a new user". Since i haven't included an active login system, this approach should help meanwhile. Thanks for directing me clearly. Sadly, i can't give you an up-vote as i dont have a min 15 points, but my sincere thanks. On a separate note, I am curious though, how can a DDoS attack be deterred for generic page?

Comment: DDOS is a separate problem from transaction-states. For DDOSs you typically only have the IP to go on, but if it's too distributed even that won't help. Search around for similar discussions, it's a totally different topic.

Comment: And you *can* accept the answer, even if you may not be able to up vote it.

Answer (score 1):

if there is a login, then my solution might work for you..

if it is in multiple browser, that means  in second browser user has to login again ..

So you make a note in your DB, where user info/login info is stored that once login you wont be able to login again...

Blocking a user from same browser in different Tab  might not be possible

Thanks

Comment: No there isn't an active login. But i get your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Store the IP Address, and check each time with this value and URL requested, with this you can decide which one can see your webpage (how many times too).

[**Restrict multiple page access by a user from the same IP**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10393478/1343222)